# Android SDK mapView. Get map zoom level/position

Tags: android, overriding, android-2.2-froyo, android-mapview

I have the map working on android and am able to populate it with overlays.

But the overlay ability is only so good. If I add too many overlays and refresh too often, I can create an app that is very processor-hard (useless).

What I want to do is only load the overlays that are within the zoom level of the map.

How to I get at what level the map is zoomed using Google APIS, overlays, itemized, and geopoints?

Thanks,

Comment: `map.getZoomLevel()` where map is your mapview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getZoomLevel`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#getZoomLevel%28%29) and [`getMapCenter`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#getMapCenter%28%29) methods on MapView. You might also read through the [MapView class documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView).

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get that from class without any method.

```
     map.getCameraPosition().zoom
```